# How to execute RawSql against the context

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I currently have a project that I'm working on, which has a database connected to it. In said database I need to query some tables that don't have a relationship. I need to get a specific set of data in order to display it on my user interface. However I need to be able to reference the returned data put it into a list and convert it into json. I have a stored procedure that needs to just be executed against the context because it's retrieving data from many different tables.

I've tried using `ExecuteSqlCommand` but that doesn't work, because it returns -1 and can't put it into a list.

I've tried using linq to select the columns I want however it's really messy and I cannot retrieve the data as easily.

I've tried using `FromSql`, however that needs a model to execute against the context which is exactly what I don't want.

```cs
public string GetUserSessions(Guid memberId)
{
    string sql = $"EXECUTE dbo.GetUserTrackByMemberID @p0";
    var session = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, memberId);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
    return json;
}
```

This is the `ExecuteSqlCommand` example, this returns -1 and cannot be put into a list as there will be more than one session.

```cs
public string GetUserSessions(Guid memberId)
{
    var session = _context.MemberSession.Where(ms => ms.MemberId == memberId).Select(s => new Session() { SessionId = 
                s.SessionId, EventId = s.Session.EventId, CarCategory = s.Session.CarCategory, AirTemp = s.Session.AirTemp,
                TrackTemp = s.Session.TrackTemp, Weather = s.Session.Weather, NumberOfLaps = s.Session.NumberOfLaps, SessionLength = s.Session.SessionLength,
                Event = new Event() { EventId = s.Session.Event.EventId, TrackId = s.Session.Event.TrackId, Name = s.Session.Event.Name, NumberOfSessions = 
                s.Session.Event.NumberOfSessions, DateStart = s.Session.Event.DateStart, DateFinish = s.Session.Event.DateFinish, TyreSet = s.Session.Event.TyreSet,
                Track = new Track() { TrackId = s.Session.Event.Track.TrackId, Name = s.Session.Event.Track.Name, Location = s.Session.Event.Track.Location, TrackLength 
                = s.Session.Event.Track.TrackLength, NumberOfCorners = s.Session.Event.Track.NumberOfCorners} } });
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
    return json;
}
```

This is using Linq, however it's really messy and I feel there's probably a better way to do this, and then when retrieving the data from json it's a lot bigger pain.

```cs
public string GetUserSessions(Guid memberId)
{
    var session = _context.MemberSession.FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.GetUserSessionByMemberID {memberId}").ToList();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
    return json;
}
```

This is the ideal way I would like to do it, however since I'm using the `MemberSession` model it will only retrieve that data from the stored procedure which is in the `MemberSession` table, however I want data that is in other tables as well....

```cs
public string GetUserSessions(Guid memberId)
{
    var session = _context.MemberSession.Where(ms => ms.MemberId == memberId).Include("Session").Include("Event").ToList();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
    return json;
}
```

I tried this way but because the `Event` table has no reference / relationship to `MemberSession` it returns an error.

As I've previously stated in the `RawSql` example I'm only getting the table data that is in the `MemberSession` table, no other tables.

There are no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
     string query = $"Exec [dbo].[YOUR_SP]";
     List<ResponseList> obj = context.Database.SqlQuery<ResponseList>(query).ToList();
     string JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: ResponseList class should be same in definition as SP output

Comment: That's the whole issue. I don't have a class that fits all the data that's in the SP output...

Comment: you mean to say the response is Dynamic?